# Верстка неправильная в Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, вёрстка

Почему в Internet Explorer 11 верстка неправильная? Если убрать псевдоэлемент, то отображается нормально.

```
 .gf_page_steps {
        font-family: 'Proxima';
        margin: 10px 60px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: relative;
        &:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #e5e9ed;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5px;
            top: 47%;
            left: 0;
        }
    }

.gf_step {
    border: 5px solid #e5e9ed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 1px 4px 1px 7px;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}
```

[image: C]
[image: IE]

Comment: Напишите в вопросе, ie какой версии?

Comment: @ Andrey Mihalev  там же написано На IE11 не работает.

Comment: префиксы пропишите, флексы плохо работают в IE11

Comment: префиксы не спасли.

Comment: @RomanStrokan надеюсь вы `sass` компилировали  )

Comment: @Swartex Само собой компилировал))

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про IE10 и ниже то можно попробовать использовать этот полифил https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility